# Go struct pointers not unique

Tags: pointers, struct, go

I'm trying to create a map of elements. I wanted to use a pointer rather then an integer as a key. The problem is... I keep getting the same pointer. No matter how many times I create it. Why is this? How do I get a real pointer, without using the unsafe package if possible.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Thingy struct{}

var things map[*Thingy]int

func main() {
    things = make(map[*Thingy]int)

    thing1 := new(Thingy)
    tracePointer("thing1", thing1)
    things[thing1] = 1

    thing2 := new(Thingy)
    tracePointer("thing2", thing2)
    things[thing2] = 2

    thing3 := &Thingy{}
    tracePointer("thing3", thing3)
    things[thing3] = 3

    fmt.Printf("Amount of things: %d\n", len(things))
}

func tracePointer(identifier string, obj interface{}) {
    fmt.Printf("%s pointer: %p\n", identifier, obj)
}
```

Ouput:

```
thing1 pointer: 0x546570
thing2 pointer: 0x546570
thing3 pointer: 0x546570
Amount of things: 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`struct{}` is a special case, it always uses 0 bytes of memory and will always have the same address.

If you just want a dummy pointer, you can use `type Thingy byte`.

```
thing1 pointer: 0x10328000
thing2 pointer: 0x10328020
thing3 pointer: 0x10328021
Amount of things: 3
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/EX4uG0XJpA)

//edit

As [James Henstridge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25954237/go-struct-pointers-not-unique/25954321#comment40658165_25954321) pointed out in the comments, `struct{}`'s address changes if they are inside a bigger struct.

http://play.golang.org/p/51_PhqDNhk

Comment: Pointers to empty `struct{}` variables don't always have the same address: If they are part of a larger data structure rather than being allocated independently, their address will point somewhere within that structure.  E.g. http://play.golang.org/p/51_PhqDNhk